# JQuery UI sortable list on fluid grid snapping to left while dragging

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery-ui sortable list in a twitter bootstrapped app using a fluid grid. All elements in the list are centered using `margin:0 auto`.

Everything works ok data wise, but when the user drags an element of the list, it visually snaps to the left while dragging, probably because of the position being set to absolute by jquery.

Is there a way to override this behaviour?

**UPDATE**

Here are the possibly relevant bits of code:

*HTML structure*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span10">
            <div id="sortable-list" data-update-url="some-url">
            <span id="position-zero"></span>
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item-inner">Some text</div>
                    <div class="item-toolbar"></div>
                </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS bits*

```
.row-fluid {
    width:100%;
}

.item-container {
margin:0 auto;
width:1205px;
}

.item-inner {
margin: 0 auto;
width:1163px;
}

.item-toolbar {
margin:0 auto;
display:none;
width:1203px;
}

#list-column {
margin: 0 auto 300px 0;
min-height:500px;
}
```

*JS (Coffeescript)*

```
jQuery ->
    $("#sortable-list").sortable
    axis: 'y'
    placeholder: "item-placeholder"
    handle: '.icon-move'
    sort: ->
        $('.item-toolbar').hide()
    update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, I'd say you'd want a position:relative on a parent element of the sortable list.

Comment: post some code so we can take a look

Comment: andres-ilich and @galaxy, thanks a lot! I've updated the question with some code. Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: @rapcal you're trying to center a fixed-width container inside a fluid-container? Why even use a fluid-container at all?

Comment: @andres-ilich I was just trying to gain some space on big monitors for what is now quite a messy UI. But I guess you're right, it doesn't make sense. Better go the hard way and change everything to fixed width (can't use a fluid container for the child elements).